# Using Archetype designer and can't select Root Archetype Id

Tags: templates, archetypes, openehr

I'm trying to create my first template and when i'm supposed to be choosing Root Archetype Id nothing comes up. What am i doing wrong?[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think i solved it myself, by enabling updates and downloading the correct Root Archetype Id. This enabled me to create a new template.